# What LauncherPro Shortcuts Have You Used?

Tags: customization, launcherpro

If you have LauncherPro you may be familiar with one of it's powerful features: [**LauncherPro Shortcuts**](http://www.launcherpro.com/2010/08/19/launcherpro-v0-7-6-0-out-in-the-wild/).

By using the [LauncherPro Shortcut Generator](http://www.launcherpro.com/shortcutcreator/), you can create powerful custom "shortcuts" that can access almost any function in your device that has an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) *([see also Open Intents](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable))*.

The shortcuts are almost mini apps in their ability to perform complex function like activating settings on your device, adding events in your calendar, sending to a particular email...  I believe that LauncherPro Shortcuts may be able to solve [Dmitriy's problem here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/manual-rotation-of-phone).

It basically opens the door to accomplishing things and accessing functions that you normally would need to be a developer to do.  Unfortunately due to the lack of documentation, it's still pretty difficult to use.  The author has [a thread on his forum](http://www.launcherpro.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2587) for people to post their Custom Shortcuts, as forums go, out of the 210 posts, 99.99% of them are people asking how to use it.  It is very frustrating finding the actual shortcuts.

I think the SE format will serve as a better mechanism for listing the Custom Shortcuts, and cutting out all the noise.

In order to keep this orderly please follow the following guidelines:

1. One Shortcut per Answer
2. **Only post working LauncherPro Shortcuts** (anything else will be deleted)
3. If you have questions or comments about a shortcut, post it in the comments.

Post it in the following format that will allow others to recreate the shortcut:

### Shortcut Name (make it descriptive)

**Notes:**  Any notes about what it does and how it works.  Also, anything else that needs to be explained.

**Form Fields:**

- Action:
- Package Name:
- Class Name:
- MIME Type:
- Data:
- Categories:
- Extras (Type / Name / Value):

***(not all fields are required so you can delete the ones you don't use)***

---

**In order to make it easy you can cut and paste the following template code into your answer:**

```
##Shortcut Name 

**Notes:**  Type notes here...

**Form Fields:**

 - Action:
 - Package Name:
 - Class Name:
 - MIME Type:
 - Data:
 - Categories:
 - Extras (Type / Name / Value):
```

---

***I thought about making this a Community Wiki, but decided to keep it a normal question so people can get rep for the useful shortcuts they post (and encourage people to create useful shortcuts that don't already exist).***

Comment: Yikes, these LauncherPro shortcuts are harder than I thought.  I can't get any to work.

Answer (score 1):

### LauncherPro Preferences

**Notes:**  Here's one to get us started that I took from Fede's forum post.  It opens up the LauncherPro preferences screen.

**Form Fields:**

- **Action:**  android.intent.action.MAIN
- **Package Name:**  com.fede.launcher
- **Class Name:**  com.fede.launcher.LauncherPreferencesActivity